# How to ensure that a bot/scraper does not get blocked

Tags: screen-scraping, web-scraping, bots

I coded a simple scraper , who's job is to go on several different pages of a site. Do some parsing , call some URL's that are otherwise called via AJAX , and store the data in a database.

Trouble is , that sometimes my ip is blocked after my scraper executes. What steps can I take so that my ip does not get blocked? Are there any recommended practices? I have added a 5 second gap between requests to almost no effect. The site is medium-big(need to scrape several URLs)and my internet connection slow, so the script runs for over an hour. Would being on a faster net connection(like on a hosting service) help ?

Basically I want to code a well behaved bot.

lastly I am not POST'ing or spamming .

Edit: I think I'll break my script into 4-5 parts and run them at different times of the day.

Comment: Have you asked the people responsible for the website?

Comment: Ask the webmaster of the site to allow you to take their information without charge or sanction.

Comment: Step #1) Don't scrape. Step #2) Ask permission

Comment: I asked them, but they ignored the question. But I do have the permission to use the gathered data. that part of the question they didn't ignore.

Comment: Probably, the only way for you is to use a proxy-anonymizer

Comment: Use a hosted server for speed and scrape gently spreading the requests over a 24 hour period! Mimic the actions of a normal visitor where you can and don't try grabbing hundreds of pages in one hit as even with a proxy you'll still trip alarms. Finally.. Make sure your script is efficient and not re-fetching the same data twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your bot so that it is more polite, i.e. don't sequentially fetch everything, but add delays in strategic places.

Comment: how much delay? currently its sleep(5) after every request.

Comment: how about `sleep(rand() % 60 + 10)`?

Comment: and maybe add bandwidth limiting on the fetches.

Answer (score 2):

You could use rotating proxies, but that wouldn't be a very well behaved bot. Have you looked at the site's robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Following guidelines set in robots.txt is a good first step.  There are tools such as import.io and morph.io.  There are also packages/ plugins for servers.  For example [x-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray); a node.js which have options to assist in quickly writing responsible scrapers e.g. throttle, delays, max connections etc.